# Запятая, закрывающая как бы уточнение, нам не мешает?

Tags: пунктуация, причастный-оборот, уточнения

> В спектакле прозвучало большинство из них – на оригинальную,
>   стилизованную под народную, музыку.

После *народную*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стилистически корректней, а также пунктуационно проще такой вариант:

> В спектакле прозвучало большинство из них – на оригинальную музыку, стилизованную под народную.

Филологи-стилисты (например, Г. Я. Солганик) неоднократно замечали, что причастный или какой-либо другой оборот («стилизованную под народную»), разрывающий словосочетание («оригинальную музыку»), создает стилистически несовершенную ситуацию.

Тем не менее, если оставить все как есть, то уточняющий оборот («стилизованную под народную») должен быть обособлен:

> В спектакле прозвучало большинство из них – на оригинальную *(в чем заключается оригинальность?)*, **стилизованную под народную,** музыку.

Также возможен взгляд на «стилизованную под народную» как на распространенное определение. В этом случае запятая будет ставится только между однородными определениями:

> В спектакле прозвучало большинство из них – на оригинальную, стилизованную под народную музыку.

Правило: http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_179

Answer (score 2):

**В спектакле прозвучало большинство из них – на оригинальную, стилизованную под народную, музыку.**

**Такой вариант возможен** (уточняется, **в чем заключена оригинальность**). При упрощении конструкции значение уточнения теряется.

Но если определительный оборот имеет уточняющее значение, то он обособляется (выделяется запятыми с двух сторон): В утренней прохладе разлит горький запах полыни, смешанный с нежным, **похожим на миндаль**, ароматом повилики (Купр.) https://profilib.net/chtenie/27738/ditmar-rozental-spravochnik-po-russkomu-yazyku-punktuatsiya-13.php